# Changing deployment target from 8.0 to 7.1 as next update?

Tags: ios, app-store

My app supports from deployment target - iOS 7.1.
Could we submit an update with deployment target - iOS 8.0 and submit another update in 10 days with deployment target - iOS 7.1 again? I don't seem to find any issue doing this, just want to be sure.

Thank you!

Comment: It may affect depend upon your functionality. Is your app is APNs enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iOS Deployment Target can be whatever you wish it to be. The main requirement that Apple has is that your app submission is compiled against the latest SDK at the time (currently Apple is accepting base SDK of iOS 9, but it will change to iOS 10).

When you downgrade the deployment target back down to 8, the only thing you have to ensure is that you're not calling any iOS 9+ APIs, otherwise you'll be creating a lot of crash reports.